# How to properly import google cloud libraries in python3.6 in MACOS?

Tags: mac-osx, google-cloud-platform, python

I'm running a python3.6 project that uses the google cloud libraries:

```
from google.cloud import secretmanager

def access_secret_version(project_id, secret_id, version_id=1):
    """
    Access the payload for the given secret version if one exists. The version
    can be a version number as a string (e.g. "5") or an alias (e.g. "latest").
    """
    # Create the Secret Manager client.
    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()

    # Build the resource name of the secret version.
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_id}/versions/{version_id}"

    # Access the secret version.
    response = client.access_secret_version(request={"name": name})

    # Print the secret payload.
    #
    # WARNING: Do not print the secret in a production environment - this
    # snippet is showing how to access the secret material.
    payload = response.payload.data.decode("UTF-8")
    print("Plaintext: {}".format(payload))
    print(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    access_secret_version('my-project', 'APAC_URL')
    access_secret_version('my-project', 'APAC_SECRET')
    access_secret_version('my-project', 'PASSWORD')
```

However, I couldn't find a way to properly import the google cloud libraries with `pip install`
I haved tried `venv/bin/pip install google-api-python-client` and  `pip install -U google-cloud-secret-manager`, and the console messages show that the installation was successful. However when I run the above code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "utils/secret_accessor.py", line 1, in <module>
    from google.cloud import secretmanager
  File "/Users/my-code-base/automated_test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/secretmanager/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from google.cloud.secretmanager_v1.services.secret_manager_service.async_client import (
  File "/Users/my-code-base/automated_test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/secretmanager_v1/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .services.secret_manager_service import SecretManagerServiceClient
  File "/Users/my-code-base/automated_test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/secretmanager_v1/services/secret_manager_service/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .client import SecretManagerServiceClient
  File "/Users/my-code-base/automated_test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/secretmanager_v1/services/secret_manager_service/client.py", line 27, in <module>
    from google.api_core import gapic_v1  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/my-code-base/automated_test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from google.api_core.gapic_v1 import config
  File "/Users/my-code-base/automated_test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/config.py", line 23, in <module>
    import grpc
  File "/Users/my-code-base/automated_test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from grpc._cython import cygrpc as _cygrpc
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/my-code-base/automated_test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyErr_FormatFromCause
  Referenced from: /Users/my-code-base/automated_test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/my-code-base/automated_test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

I don't know why it is so difficult to even get the libraries installed properly. It should be a very simple and smooth process. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please have look into the [Secret Manager Library](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries#installing_the_client_library) , have you follow those steps?

Comment: Questions about setting up your programming environment belong on [so].

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself here:

add the below line to `requirements.txt`:

`google-cloud-secret-manager==2.0.0`

Then install with `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Somehow this did not work at first. After some trial-and-error, it finally worked.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the next steps or [the Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries) in order to set up Python Client Library:

- First set up a [Python development environment](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup)
- To run the client library, you must first [set up authentication](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) by creating a service account and setting an environment variable
- You will need to use the Python Client Library as mentioned in the following [Secret Manager Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library). You have to set the Project ID, Secret ID etc..

You can also follow the  next CodeLabs to set up [Python Client Library for Secret Manager](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/secret-manager-python/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0)

Also please have a look into the [Python Client for Secret Manager API](https://googleapis.dev/python/secretmanager/latest/index.html)

I hope it helps. Let me know if you have any issues when performing the previous steps.